# Handsontable Scrolling Inverted on MS Edge

Tags: handsontable

For some reason the scrolling of Handsontable is inverted when using the Microsoft Edge browser. You can reproduce this issue by opening the following link in MS Edge.

https://handsontable.com/examples.html?headers

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the scrolling working normally (i.e. scrolling down on the mouse wheel makes the scroll bar go down and visa versa) via a Handsontable setting, CSS property etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug. Inverted scrolling in MS Edge was fixed within [#4874](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/pull/4874) PR and released in v[0.38.0](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/releases/tag/0.38.0). There's no need to work around this issue anymore.